# rewrite /path to root domain(/) for Single page application with any method

Tags: firebase, nginx, single-page-application, kong

There are lots of solutions available for rewriting non-SPA application path routing to root domain. For ex. - `https://example.com/path` can be routed and mapped to root domain `https://example.com` but my situation is pretty *unique*. I have a SPA application which generates dynamic links and (#) or (anchor) comes with path. My requirement is map `https://example.com` to `https://example.com/#/path`. Is it even possible. Below are the tools and techs I have utilised so far:

1. google load balancer host rules
2. nginx rewrite rules
3. firebase rewrite rules
4. nginx ingress controller annotation `rewrite-target`
5. kong rewrite-rules.
6. cloudflare workers

But none of them work and it always routes back to homepage rather then hitting `/#/path`. Any solution or tool will be helpful

Comment: In your question you wrote: My requirement is map `https://example.com` to `https://example.com/#/path`. Do you mean mapping `https://example.com/path` to `https://example.com/#/path`?

Comment: No. I mean mapping root domain to `/path`.

Comment: Then the short answer is no, it isn't possible from server side. The `#/path` URI part, called *fragment* in [URI parts terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Definition), isn't even passed to web server while requesting a resource from the user browser, so you can't distinguish requests `http://example.com/#/path` and `http://example.com` from the server side. You can do it from client browser if you can add some custom javascript to your SPA, otherwise it is impossible.